# Loop generated string

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, arraylist

I'm trying to create a string from looping within my array. Then the string is to be placed in a SelectCommand.

The foreach loop is:

```
 foreach (Object obj in arrFields)
            {
                String.Join(" {0}", obj);
            }
```

and the SelectCommand is:

```
 Custom.SelectCommand = "SELECT " + String.Join(", ", arrFields) + " FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID = " + a;
```

The closest I've came to getting this to work is the following

string newList

```
            foreach (Object obj in arrFields)
            {
                newList = string.Format(" {0}", obj);
            }

 Custom.SelectCommand = "SELECT " + newList + " FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID = " + a;
```

The issue I run into with this one is that I end up with a ',' right before FROM - how do I prevent this ',' from being inserted before the FROM statement?

Comment: May not be directly helpful, but String.Join shall give new strings every time it operates over an existing string, so alots of Heap strings created. Use StringBuilder for efficiency.

Comment: @Zenwalker - `String.Join` uses `UnSafeCharBuffer` to build the string and doesn't create a heap of intermediate strings.

Comment: Your right about using UnSafeCharbuffer thus making Join faster but only for smaller arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want, given that `arrFields` is an `ArrayList`:

```
Custom.SelectCommand = "SELECT " + string.Join("," , arrFields.ToArray()) + 
                       " FROM Employee WHERE Employee_ID = " + a;
```

Comment: When I try using that line of code I run into: "The multi-part identifier "System.Collections.ArrayList" could not be bound. 
"

Comment: Oh, it's an ArrayList? Replace arrFields by arrFields.ToArray() and it will work.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! By not having the .ToArray() what was the code trying to do?

Comment: Wrong typing. The things is: `string.Join` requires a `string[]` and you were passing an `ArrayList`. Also, remember to accept the answer if you consider it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your replacing the newList object in the loop every time you iterate. Use contact nation or stringBuilder for efficiency

Comment: I don't think that there's any need to use `StringBuilder` here for efficiency. The number of concatenations is low and the string sizes small. Code readability would be my first priority in this situation.

Comment: well i dont know how many iterations did the code have, even creating smaller objects over heap multiple times i dont think its efficient right? May be you have to performance study on that.

Comment: I just did a test concatenating a string of 100 characters to itself 100 times - `+=` => 0.3966ms - `StringBuilder` => 0.2611ms. Doing 1000 x 1000 led to 2,092ms vs 0.8826ms. So for most concatenation situations plain old `+=` is fine.

Comment: Well i also noted that, if you dont specific string[] in join arguments, it internally uses Stringbuilder itself to do the job other wise as you said unSafecharbuffer!